# .dll.config file not found when running in IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I am calling a webservice but the .dll.config file with the webservice bindings is not found.
Let's say the code for calling the webservice is in a DLL named *webservicecall.dll* and the generated config file is *webservicecall.dll.config*.
Both files are located in IIS (6.0), **DefaultWebSite\testserver\bin**

When calling the command to use the webservice, I get an error indicating that the config file was not found.

To test the WebService call, I created a console application *TestWebServiceAccess.exe* and used the same config file (just renamed it to *TestWebServiceAccess.exe.config*). This works fine.

Even the unit tests in "webservicecall.dll" use the .dll.config file correctly, just when the whole thing is hosted in IIS it doesn't work.

This is the error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WEBSERVICE1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Are there any configuration options in IIS to get the thing working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .NET configuration system will **not** read config files for assemblies (`.dll.config`).

You need to put your config into the host apps' config - since you're running in IIS, you need to put your config into `web.config` for it to be used and interpreted by the .NET configuration system.

Comment: +1. I agree. I'd also like to add (by way of explanation). No matter what kind of app you're using. An assembly (.dll in .NET) is always loaded in the memory space of an application. So as far as the assembly is concerned it's "config" file is that of the application. For ASP.NET application, things are a bit different (but the concept is the same) due to the fact the ASP.NET application are also effectively assemblies and are loaded by a worker process. So they've made a few "adjustments" whereby ASP.NET apps use a file called web.config. Instead of a config file with the name of the app.

Answer (score 1):

the filename for .config files in IIS is web.config, it resides (or should reside) in the root of your application. If you just have one website/webservice (application) on your IIS, the web.config is most likely to be found in the root folder of your website. In your case, it might also be found in the \testserver folder.

web.config files in a subfolder can contain keys that override keys in a web.config file in the root folder.

If you're using Visual Studio, the web.config file should automatically be edited by VS when you add a web service to your project.